# ¿Cómo cambiar de posición la ecuación de regresión en un gráfico con ggplot2 y ggpmisc?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Con los paquetes `ggplot2`, `ggpmisc` y el siguiente código he podido graficar una nube de puntos con su recta de regresión e imprimir en el gráfico tanto la ecuación como el valor de `R^2`.

El problema como se puede ver en la imagen es que se sobreponen sobre algunos puntos, lo que quiero es poder mover la ecuación a otra posición donde no se mezcle con ellos (en este caso alineada a la derecha preferiblemente), agradezco sus soluciones.

[image: Gráfico resultante]

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=P, y=C)) + 
  ggtitle("Curva de data") + 
  geom_jitter(color="green1")+
  xlab("P") + 
  ylab("C") + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm,formula = y~x)+
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y~x,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(q)~`=`~",
               eq.x.rhs = "~italic(p)",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., 
                                 sep = "*plain(\",\")~")), 
               parse = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ver la documentación del paquete `ggpmisc` la función `stat_poly_eq`, cuenta con los siguientes parámetros, con los respectivos valores que pueden tomar:

```
 label.x.npc = "right", "left", "middle o center"
 label.y.npc = "bottom", "top", "middle o center"
```

La configuración por *default* es: `label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = "top"`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

x <- 1:100
y <- (x + x^2)
Data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, group = c("P", "C"))

ggplot(Data, aes(x, y)) + 
    ggtitle("Curva de data") + 
    geom_jitter(color="green1")+
    xlab("P") + 
    ylab("C") + 
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)+
    stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,

                 # ----------------------------------------------
                 # linea agregada
                 # ----------------------------------------------
                 label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = "bottom",
                 # ----------------------------------------------

                 eq.with.lhs = "italic(q)~`=`~",
                 eq.x.rhs = "~italic(p)",
                 aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., 
                                   sep = "*plain(\",\")~")), 
                 parse = TRUE)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También es posible configurar la posición de la ecuación, en función a los valores del eje `x` e `y`, para ello sólo cambiar `label.x.npc = "right"`, `label.y.npc = "bottom"` por:

```
label.x = 75, label.y = 2500
```

O los valores que se necesiten, porque dichos parámetros por *default* son: `label.x = NULL, label.y = NULL`

Comment: En efecto esa es la solución, muchas gracias.